# What is the processing libraries processing.js can execute?

Tags: processing, processing.js

I want to create socket connection with processing.js. But processing.js can't use java library. Can I use processing.net.* ? And What is the processing libraries processing.js can execute? I can't find the list of libraries. Help me!!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Processing.JS has no support for Processing libraries. But since it is JavaScript, you can use a framework like jQuery and any libraries for jQuery.

As far as socket connections, take a look at Socket.io (http://socket.io/) to connect to a socket from JavaScript. You can use JavaScript inside Processing.JS.

Answer (score 0):

There ARE some libraries which are 'cross-platform', that is, they work with (at least) Java and Javascript. Two examples I know of are [Guido](https://github.com/fjenett/Guido) and [RiTa](http://www.rednoise.org/RiTa/), but there may well be others...