# Can't import ControlP5 in Processing.js

Tags: import, processing.js, control-p5

```
import controlP5.*;
ControlP5 gui;

void setup()
{
  gui = new ControlP5(this);
}
```

The previous code, when run in Processing.js gave the error: "Uncaught Processing.js: Unable to execute pjs sketch: ReferenceError: ControlP5 is not defined" even though ControlP5 is installed on my computer. Can anyone please help me to make this problem go away so that I can use ControlP5 in Processing.js?

Answer (score 4):

Processingjs provides a javascript 'virtual machine' to run the core processing api.  `controlp5` is a processing library written in java.  Therefore, you would need a version of this library written in javascript.

There was some discussion of a port a while back, follow up with this thread:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/processingjs/dfzwPQ4Wqus

See this post for more information on libraries which have been ported:
[What is the processing libraries processing.js can execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439212/what-is-the-processing-libraries-processing-js-can-execute)